# Суть наследования в php

Tags: php, ооп, наследование

Добрый день. Прошу помощи разобраться в сути наследования языка php.

В мануале есть такой пример:
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

```
<?php

class A {
    private function foo() {
        echo "success!\n";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
        static::foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
   /* foo() будет скопирован в В, следовательно его область действия по прежнему А,
      и вызов будет успешен*/
}

class C extends A {
    private function foo() {
        /* исходный метод заменен; область действия нового метода С */
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
$c = new C();
$c->test();   //не верно
?>
```

Меня смущает комментарий

> /* foo() будет скопирован в В, следовательно его область действия по
>   прежнему А,
>         и вызов будет успешен*/

Что значит скопирован? Скопирован всмысле отнаследован? Но ведь невозможно наследовать приватные методы и свойства.
И правильно ли я понимаю что вызвать $b->foo() нельзя как раз потому, что метод  приватный? Но почему тогда из метода test доступно this->foo(), ведь this указывает нам на экземпляр текущего обьекта, а не класса? А объект у нас b.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При наследовании - унаследуются метод `test()` и метод `foo()`, у каждого будет область видимости А, хоть и класс В, следовательно когда вы обращаетесь к методу `test()` в классе В - он может обратиться к `foo()` т.к. у них одна область видимости. Но в случае с классом С - у вас переобъявляется метод `foo()` а следовательно у него область видимости уже становится С и метод с областью видимости А не может к нему обращаться, так как это приватный метод. А значит чтоб вы могли использовать метод `test()` - его тоже нужно переопределить в классе С

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но тогда это противоречит мануалу:Например, когда вы расширяете класс, дочерний класс наследует все публичные и защищенные методы из родительского класса. До тех пор пока не будут эти методы переопределены, они будут сохранять свою исходную функциональность.

Comment: Нет, не противоречит. Оно на приведенном вами примере как раз и работает корректно "до тех пор, пока вы не переопределите метод". Тогда этот метод уже становится методом класса С, но приватные методы на то и приватные методы - они будут доступны только методам данного класса, т.е. унаследованные приватные методы будут доступны только унаследованным методам, но никак не переопределенным. Тут 2 варианта - либо сделать метод `test() `публичным, либо переопределять его вместе с методом `foo()`

Comment: Противоречие в том, что вы говорите, что оба метода наследуются, а в в мануале говорится, что приватные не наследуются.

Comment: Перефразирую. Когда вы обращаетесь в классе С к унаследованному методу, это как бы ссылка на метод класса А, у которого и есть нужный вам приватный метод, т.е. по сути вы работаете как бы в классе А. Но как только вы переопределили публичный метод в классе С - вы уже будете работать с методом класса С, у которого нет приватных методов класса А, а значит будет ошибка.

Comment: Я всегда думал что this это ссылка на конкретный объект. Но получатся, что если this вызывается в унаследованном методе, то this начинает ссылаться уже не на объект, а на класс.

Comment: Ну примерно так и получается - пока метод класса А не переопределен в классе С, это по-прежнему метод класса А

Comment: Еще небольшое замечание. Вы пишете :Но как только вы переопределили публичный метод в классе С - вы уже будете работать с методом класса С, у которого нет приватных методов класса А, а значит будет ошибка. Но ошибка возникает только если вызывать метод статически.

Comment: А вы обратите внимание на то, что если в этом примере закоментировать вызов static и оставить только $this - выведется success! дважды, хотя в классе С и будет переопределен метод foo() тем, что он ничего выводить не должен. В этом и разница - static:: пытается работать с тем классом в котором написан, в данном случае А, а $this будет ссылаться уже сперва на переопределенный метод и только если он не переопределен - на метод родительского класса.

Comment: этот код выведе success! трижды и только при вызове static::foo(); будет ошибка, так как вызов перенаправляется на класс С и приватный метод. Спасибо большое. Очень помогли разобраться.

Comment: Я имел в виду этот код выведет дважды (чтоб без ошибок - просто закоментировать static вызов)
`public function test() {$this->foo();/*static::foo();*/}`

Comment: Не сразу понял. Вы правы. Спасибо.